# Vertex AI forecasting AutoML giving different answers for same input data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, forecasting, google-cloud-automl, automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I trained Vertex AI forecasting AutoML model one with target column as String and other numeric input features as String then I trained another AutoML model with target column as float and other input features as Integer.

The predictions are different for both the models. The data is same only the datatypes/schema changed.

Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/data-types-tabular#forecasting) says:

> When you train a model with a feature with a numeric transformation,
> Vertex AI applies the following data transformations to the feature,
> and uses any that provide signal for training:
>
> - The value converted to float32.

So both the data should be same even after transformation.
Why would results be different? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have follow the steps to have a forecasting model as show on [Build an AutoML Forecasting Model with Vertex AI](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/automl-forecasting-with-vertex-ai) and reach the conclusion that vertex AI compress a lot of the steps of the prediction model generation so it can be easily operate by users.

I think the most reasonable answer for your observation among strings and numeric values resides in the way data processing is performed to generate our prediction models. I think you will not find inside vertex AI documentation as it would mean to disclose how vertex AI code works and handles its [Feature Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_engineering) and train steps to generate the models, which is protected.

Regardless, Lets speculate a bit, I think the difference among datatypes conversion might occur when datatype is converted and passed to the algorithm for processing. Lets said a linear regression sample, you will find that the slightest variation on data conversion can affect the outcome of your prediction model which could also be what is happening here.